# How to have a variable number of arguments, of unknown determined type?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I don't really know what the proper title for this is, so excuse what I wrote. I think it is best to show by example.

```
void foo(std::pair<std::string, T>, std::pair<std::string, U>, std::pair<std::string, Z>, ...);
```

where the T, U, and Z can be many types, but the list keeps going to a variable amount of parameters. I know you can use a parameter pack and just assume they're passing objects along this line, but then when you call the function you can't call a pairs aggregate initializers.

```
template<typename ...args>
void foo(args... values);
//the following isn't allowed, cause it doesn't know the type. (this is what I want it to look like)
foo({"hi",5}, {"hello", true});
```

Is it even possible what I'm trying to do? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in C++17 you can leverage CTAD ([Class Template Argument Deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)) and  using `std::string`'s `operator""s` to have

```
template<typename ...args>
void foo(args... values) {}
// or to make sure pair types are provided
//template<typename ...args>
//void foo(std::pair<std::string, args>... values) {}

int main()
{
    using std::pair;
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    foo(pair{"hi"s, 5}, pair{"hello"s, true});
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do that without the pair{...}?

Comment: @JosephGrimaldo Unfortunetly, no.  `{stuff}` does't have a type so `foo({stuff})` will never be able to deduce a type.  That means if you want a variadic template, you have to specify the type of each `{}`.  Otherwise you would have to do it the old school way and provide N overloads where each one has one more parameter then the last overload.

Answer (score 1):

You might do following to constraint parameter to pairs:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
void foo(std::pair<std::string, Ts>... values);
```

Call has to be similar to:

```
foo(std::pair{std::string("hi"),5}, std::pair{std::string("hello"), true});
foo<int, bool>({"hi",5}, {"hello", true});
```

`{"hi",5}` has no type, so cannot allow to deduce template type.
In that case, you have to provide template parameter.

If you provide correct pairs (`std::pair<std::string, T>`, not `std::pair<const char*, T>`), then deduction can occurs.